# how to draw line chart using jqplot having flot point of series for y-axis

Tags: java, javascript, jqplot, linechart

I am using jqplot for drawing line chart. I am returning String from java to javascript that holds co-ordinate for y-axis in the format "00.04|00.70|01.22|03.49". I split this string in javascript with "|"  and that return array. Now I want to draw a line graph with y-axis coordinates as 00.04, 00.70, 01.22, 03.49 but I am not able to draw graph with specified coordinate.In order to draw graph I have to convert last co-ordinate to integer i.e 03.49 to either 3 or 4. Here is my code for javascript :

```
arrayFromJava = realJsString.split("|");
```

realJsString is the variable that stores the java string & now I split it with "|" to get array and try to draw line graph with code:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot ('chart1',[arrayFromJava] )
```

any solution? please help.

Comment: Got my problem, I had to give "ticks:" for y-axis in javascript then it takes the last coordinate in float and it draws line properly.